# How to set Signalr Connection Hub Url using web config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

Hi I'm using signalr with my MVC 5 application and its working fine. And my hub is in a separate web application. So I have to provide the hub connection URL as a parameter **instead of hard coding** it.

Here is my current url in the Web Layout page..

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("http://localhost:51734/signalr/hubs")"></script>
```

And what I need is to assign this url using configuration key in web config file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
<script src='@Url.Content(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HubUrl"])'>
</script>
```

And remember to add the `System.Configuration` Assembly reference to your project.

And in your web.config

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="HubUrl" value="http://localhost:51734/signalr/hubs" />
  </appSettings>
```